# 301 редирект с ?PAGEN_1=10 на page-10

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Нужно настроить правило, которое редиректило бы все старые страницы пагинации на сайте вида ?PAGEN_1=2 на новые вида /page-2/ и т.п. Например. Со старых

```
http://site.com/catalog/tablets/?PAGEN_1=10
```

На новые

```
http://site.com/catalog/tablets/page-10/
```